# IndexError when implementing quicksort CS50 style

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, computer-science, quicksort

As someone fairly new to programming, I am trying to implement quicksort in Python. However, I am trying to implement it in a way, that does not seem the most common one. I am using the technique explained in this video by CS50: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQiWF4E8flQ

This version of the algorithm selects a pivot at the end of the array, places a "wall" at the beginning and starts iterating the list. When it finds an item that is smaller than the pivot, it swaps that item with the item on the right side of the wall and moves the wall one position to the right. When all items are compared to the pivot, it places the pivot on the wall, and the wall moves one position to the right. This continues until the wall is at the end of the array.

So far, I have come up with this:

```
def quicksort(alist):
    quicksort_helper(alist)
    print alist

def quicksort_helper(alist):
    wall = 0
    while wall < (len(alist) - 1):
        pivot = len(alist) - 1        
        for current in range(wall, pivot):
            if alist[current] < alist[pivot]:
                alist[current], alist[wall] = alist[wall], alist[current]
                wall = wall + 1
            alist[wall], alist[pivot] = alist[pivot], alist[wall]
            wall = wall + 1
```

When I am trying to run the program I keep having problems with the array indexes of the wall and pivot, as this is the error message I am getting:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have tried a lot with the indexes, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: Please see that your code is properly formatted, might be just as well that it is because of wrong indentation

Comment: And provide the failing input (not that the algorithm is correct because `[4,2,1,1,2]` is sorted to `[2, 2, 4, 1, 1]`).

Comment: The last, unconditional swap must be after the `for current ...` loop. It inserts the pivot between the two partitions. Of course, the current code only partitions. You must apply quicksort to both partitions to the left and right to the pivot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quicksort works like this: You first partition your array so that there are three subarrays: The left array contains all elements that are smaller than the pivod, in no order. The middle "array"  is just one element, the pivot*. The right array contains all elements that are larger than or equal to the pivot.

The pivot is now known to be in its correct position. You then have to sort the left and right subarrays.

The partitioning is done with the help of the wall. The pivot's position is fixed; it is always the rightmost element. Then you conpare each element with the pivot and move it to the left of the wall if it's smaller. You must move the wall right in oder to make room for the element.

After you have looked at all elements, you have the three subarrays, but in the wrong order: left, right, pivot. (The wall is the barrier between the left and right subarrays.) In oder to bring it into the correct order, swap the element to the right of the wall with the pivot, but don't move the wall. This has to be done only once, after the partitioning loop. (Note that if the pivot happens to be the biggest element, you swap the pivot with itself, which is okay, if wasteful.)

Your algorithm uses 0 and the ength of the array as bound. That works for the whole array. When you want to sort the subarrays, you have to adjust these bounds. It is therefore a good idea to pass the bounds to the quicksort helper, so that you can recurse. (It is sutomary to make the lower bound inclusive and the upper bound exclusive, just as the index `len(a)` is one beyond the valid index range for `a` when indexing starts at zero.)

Here's a working solution:

```
def quicksort(alist):
    quicksort_helper(alist, 0, len(alist))

def quicksort_helper(alist, l, r):
    if l < r:
        wall = l

        pivot = r - 1 

        for current in range(wall, pivot):
            if alist[current] < alist[pivot]:
                alist[current], alist[wall] = alist[wall], alist[current]
                wall = wall + 1

        alist[wall], alist[pivot] = alist[pivot], alist[wall]

        quicksort_helper(alist, l, wall)
        quicksort_helper(alist, wall + 1, r)
```

*) There is a three-way Quicksort that groups all pivots of the same value together in order to improve Quicksort's poor performance with arrays that have only a few unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

The line `alist[wall], alist[pivot] = alist[pivot], alist[wall]` is executed, in some cases, after `wall` value was incremented and resulted in `len(alist)` which triggers `IndexError`.

You can use [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to debug your code, add the line `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` in your function to track the variables values.